# Warning: passing arg 1 of `spielfeldAusgeben' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm getting the compile error on the line 'spielfeldAusgeben(spielfeld);' . I tried many different thing but nothing worked. Here is the code:

```
int spielfeldAusgeben(int *spielfeld[][8]){
  int positionY;
  int positionX;
  for(positionY=0; positionY<8; positionY++){
    for(positionX=0; positionX<8; positionX++){
      printf("%d ", *(spielfeld[positionY][positionX]));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}


int main(){
  int spielfeld[8][8] = {0};
  spielfeld[0][0] = 1;
  int positionY;
  int positionX;
  char bewegungCharakter;
  printf("Willkommen zu einem Spielbrett, wo die Spielfigur sich nach oben, 
  unten, rechts und links bewegen kann.\n");
  printf("Hier ist der aktuelle Stand des Spielfelds:\n");

  for(positionY=0; positionY<8; positionY++) {
    for(positionX=0; positionX<8; positionX++) {
       spielfeld[positionY][positionX];
    }
  }
  spielfeldAusgeben(spielfeld);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Mit der Taste 'w' bewegt sich die Figur nach oben, mit 'a' nach 
  links, mit 's' nach unten und mit 'd' nach rechts.\n");
  printf("Mit 'x' beenden Sie das Programm\n");
  printf("Bitte waehlen Sie aus, welche Aktion Sie machen wollen.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Does somebody know, what the problem is?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int spielfeldAusgeben(int *spielfeld[][8]){` --> `int spielfeldAusgeben(int spielfeld[][8]){`, (`printf("%d ", spielfeld[positionY][positionX]);`)

Comment: Remove the two `*`s in the function.

Comment: Also `spielfeld[positionY][positionX];` has no effect.